pywallet needs 'bsddb' package to run, please install it
On a Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS VM I installed Python 2.7.18 via:
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz
tar xzf Python-2.7.18.tgz 
cd Python-2.7.18/
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
python --version
Python 2.7.18

pywallet downloaded via:
git clone https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet.git

Running:
python /home/john/pywallet/pywallet.py --dumpwallet --dumpwithbalance --wallet=/home/john/bitcoin/.bitcoin/wallet.dat
pywallet needs 'bsddb' package to run, please install it

Verifying Python is correct version:
python --version
Python 2.7.18

Using Python's -v (verbose) option I see:
import bsddb # directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/bsddb
# /usr/local/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.pyc matches /usr/local/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py
import bsddb # precompiled from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.pyc

The above paths contain bsddb.
bsddb was installed via:
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/24/92034482656945fc6ceb10551222b43a0ff8d0c87e15839120487820067e/bsddb3-6.2.9.tar.gz
cd bsddb3-6.2.9
sudo pip install -e /home/john/bsddb3/bsddb3-6.2.9 --log /home/john/LOG_FILE 

The above LOG_FILE shows:
Successfully installed bsddb3

I needed to use the pip install -e because pip was producing errors on the SSL/TLS front.
When I test (import bsddb):
python
Python 2.7.18 (default, Dec  7 2024, 14:38:44) 
[GCC 13.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bsddb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/bsddb/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    import _bsddb
ImportError: No module named _bsddb
>>> 

Looks like bsddb isn't installed correctly, any ideas?

your bsddb module was either not installed or not properly linked during the Python build.
to fix that we install DB Berkeley properly
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libdb-dev libdb5.3-dev

then we rebuild
cd Python-2.7.18/
sudo make clean

we reconfigure
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-dbmliborder=gdbm:ndbm:bdb

then finaly we install and build and it should be linked properly
sudo make altinstall

now it should work
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-dbmliborder=bdb --with-bdb=/usr/local
sudo make altinstall

